# How to modify javafx colorpicker?

Tags: colors, javafx, color-picker

This is my current color picker:

[image]

How can I style its color preview width, border color and radius? Is it possible to get rid of "Custom color" option in the bottom and instead of default colors use my own set of colors?

I tried to use this CSS:

```
.color-picker {
-fx-skin: "CustomSkin";
-fx-background-color: white; 
-fx-background-radius: 2; 
-fx-padding: 0;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
}

.color-picker .color-picker-label .text {
visibility: false;
}

.color-picker .color-picker-label{
-fx-scale-x: 1.53;
-fx-scale-y: 1.53;
-fx-spacing: 0;
-fx-padding: 3;
-fx-border-width: 0;
 -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
 -fx-border-radius: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled upon a similar issue when trying to modify the ColorPicker preview and hopefully the below can help others trying to make similar changes

In order to target the preview with css, you need to use .picker-color as the skin contains a pane which holds the preview as a rectangle

e.g.

```
.picker-color {
    -fx-border-color: green;
}
```

which targets this portion of the control, allowing you to change the width etc:

[image]